# folder security, cannot access .. Permission denied, huh?

Tags: debian, security, permissions

Okay, here's the thing .. I'm having trouble accessing a certain folder despite correct security settings (at least I think so). What am I missing ?

Some details:

Using Raspbian, that would be Debian Linux v8

Folder security is: `drwxrwx---  3 www-data www-data  4096 Feb 13 00:34 owncloud`

(I used `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/pi/_ext.vol/owncloud` and `sudo chmod -R 770 /media/pi/_ext.vol/owncloud` to set ownership and permissions to this owncloud folder (ext4 filesystem used))

I check access using this line: `sudo -u www-data ls -lisa /media/pi/_ext.vol/owncloud` BUT .. no access. Why ??? I just can't figure this one out :(

Any help would be very much appreciated !!

Comment: What is the ownership and permissions for each of `/media`, `/media/pi`, `/media/pi/_ext.vol`?

Comment: For /media: drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Dec 25 01:22 media  
For /media/pi: drwxr-x---+  5 root root 4096 Feb 13 14:55 pi  
For /media/pi/_ext.vol: drwxrwxrwx  5 root root 4096 Feb 13 00:19 _ext.vol  
This is an inheritance issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of the parent directory. To access a lower-level directory, www-data needs to have at least +x on every parent.

As a demonstration:

```
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo mkdir -p testdir/foo
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data ./testdir
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo ls -lah ./testdir
total 48K
drwxrwx---  3 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 .
drwxrwxrwt 17 root     root      36K Feb 13 13:56 ..
drwxrwx---  2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 foo
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo ls -lah ./testdir/foo
total 8.0K
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 .
drwxrwx--- 3 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 ..
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo chown root:root ./testdir
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo ls -lah testdir/foo
total 8.0K
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 .
drwxrwx--- 3 root     root     4.0K Feb 13 13:53 ..
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo -u www-data ls -lah testdir/foo
ls: cannot access testdir/foo: Permission denied
```

Edit to add demonstration of fix:

```
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo -u www-data ls -lah testdir/foo
ls: cannot access testdir/foo: Permission denied
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo chmod a+x ./testdir/
alex@al-core:/tmp$ sudo -u www-data ls -lah testdir/foo
total 8.0K
drwxrwx--- 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Feb 13 13:53 .
drwxrwx--x 3 root     root     4.0K Feb 13 13:53 ..
alex@al-core:/tmp$
```

However, as the directories we are talking about here are system directories installed by the operating system, you probably shouldn't be changing them.

Consider mounting the owncloud directory to a different path under /usr/local/, /var/local or /opt which are intended for the purpose of user software.

Edit 2:

As we're dealing with a USB stick here, preserving auto-mount is beneficial. It should be safe to change the parent dirs to a new group (e.g. "usbstick").

So I would do:

```
chmod a+x /media /media/pi  # may already be like this
groupadd usbstick
chown root:usbstick  /media/pi/_ext.vol
usermod -a -G usbstick www-data
```

This may not be preserved if you unplug the USB drive though, I'm not sure how Raspbian is setup. Generally speaking though, I would recommend not storing software to be run by a web user on a usb stick if you can avoid it!

Comment: Don't quite know what you did here but I understand what you're saying. So I should set 'execute' for www-data. But do I do that in the Group or Others section of the permissions? The parent folders are all owned by Root.

Comment: chmod a+x is going to be the easiest way to achieve this, will edit above. But you may not want to give the world list permissions on your directories.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Does it matter if I jump to that _ext.vol folder using a symbolic link ? Can I then leave the security on /media and /media/pi as it is by default? The /media/pi/_ext.vol is a mount point for my usb  stick.

Comment: Symlinks are literally just a file with the directory path in them, they don't affect file system permissions at all, so no you can't just link unfortunately. Will edit above again (comments are too limited).

Comment: Let me see if I got this right .. you add the root to an "usbstick" group and then change the ownership of the mountpoint '/media/pi/_ext.vol' to root:usbstick whereby you also add www-data as a member of that usbstick group? I can see how that may work, will have to try. Bit concerned though with the first line, giving 'the world' that 'x' permission.  From my example (see comments) of the current folder security, am I right in assuming I only have to alter the /media/pi permissions? (don't know what that + means after its: drwxr-x---+). (oh, probably needs "r" too, right ? : drwxr-xr-x+)

Comment: Probably should have stuck with the same notation you were using, it seems to be a source of confusion.

Setting a+x _modifies_ only the permission for "all", whereas the octal notation (e.g 700) sets it explicitly for everything. So if the permission was 700, doing chmod a+x would make it 701. If it was 704, setting a+x makes it 705.

Comment: Likewise you can do u for user and g for group. So if permissions were --- for user, u+x makes it --x, doing u+r makes it r-- and u+w makes it -w-. chmod u+rwx makes it rwx. You'll probably want to do some reading on file permissions, http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml looks like a good resource.

Comment: No worries Alex, I understood your 'adding to the existing permissions' but I'll check out your link. Oh so much still to learn about Linux ..

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah ! Now it works. I'll summarize so other users can benefit:

Even when symlinking the actual path that needs to be traversed to get there must still be honored, so when trying to reach (as 'user' www-data) ..

`/media/pi/_ext.vol/owncloud` with its: `drwxrwx---  www-data www-data`

`/media` has `drwxr-xr-x  root root`
`/media/pi` has `drwxr-x---+  root root`
`/media/pi/_ext.vol` has `drwxrwxrwx  root root`

To get access I allowed 'the world' (which in this case applies to the www-data 'user') to have `r-x` too on the 'pi' folder: `chmod a+rx /media/pi`

With `/media/pi`, `drwxr-xr-x+  root root` I can now traverse the whole path being www-data (checked every part of the path using the `sudo -u www-data ls -lisa /media/pi/_ext.vol/owncloud` command).

(note that the ownership is different / has changed going from the '_ext.vol' to the 'owncloud' folder, just to be clear)

Big thanks to Alex and techraf for the insight !

Comment: As a final note (hint hint for fellow ownCloud users) .. All things considered is /media/pi not a suitable place to use a mountpoint (see above). My Raspbian auto-mounts usb sticks there so it's tempting, but is also houses a settings subfolder with config files. Not really a good idea to open that up to your webserver. I diverted to /media where I will create that wanted mountpoint.